# Can I use old ubuntu mtp system?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, mtp

I have a walkman that uses mtp Fun, well since ubuntu 13.04 I can not get ubuntu to read/write files on this device.
 However I know that ubuntu 12.04 (first release) works on this device without any problem. 
 So what I want to know is there a way to take Files from my old ubuntu 12.04 cd and put on my ubuntu 14.04 device that will make MTP behave like it did ??

Here is a bug report as well
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1183948

Thank you in davance

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to investigate the problem you have in getting MTP to work in 14.04. If you could write to it on 12.04 you should also be able to use all the releases after 12.04 to use MTP.  I have (up to today) not have any problem using MTP with both my Cowon J3 and my S5 (all mount out of the box for several releases).

Your problem might be fixable in 14.04. If you are interested try to figure out what the problem is by examining log files (/var/log/). `tail -f /var/log/syslog` for instance and then mount the walkman, try to add files and check the log for error messages.

Besides that:

> Can I use old ubuntu mtp system?

Maybe yes. Probably: no. 1 snag you might run into: as of 13.10 MTP support is native in Ubuntu so lots of packages created have become invalid and will conflict with older versions of MTP. From the link you added: there have been changes to UDEV rules so I am inclined to lean towards no...

The usual method to install software from an older release is to either (not just MTP; this is a general method. Warning: it can mess up your system if you keep adding software from older releases, fixing the problem in the current release is the better way to go)...

- use the PPA for that older release (if there is one)
- download the debian file from that older release (and the dependencies involved) from Launchpad and use the command line tool `dpkg -i` to install all those debian files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply on old ubuntu like 13.10 this was a solution http://intr.overt.org/blog/?p=178&cpage=1#comment-17947 getting this software but according to the package owner all of this packages were included in never releases of ubuntu So I think my problem is the settings of MTP devices, so I thought maybe I can get those settings from an old ubuntu release. About ubuntu 14.04 I could not get it working. With current information on the web

Comment: I was reading the bug report. If that PPA no longer works you are running out of options I am afraid.

Comment: Yes, I know that is out of date but Now I am using ubuntu 14.04 and not older versions, but couple of days ago I had to run Live cd of ubuntu 12.04 and I noticed that my MTP device walkman was running out of the box so I thought maybe I can take some settings files out of the old 12.04 ubuntu put it on my 14.04 and get it running again. That is what I thought.

Comment: Hmm would have been my guess too but from the bugreport: there is a mentioning of udev rules. That's a core thing in Ubuntu and to me a showstopper. I wish I had a perfect method for you. I hate regressions ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time, if no one else comments I will gladly accept your answer

Comment: Leave it unaccepted and the system will kick it back to the top of the list now and then. I would rather be proven wrong :)